# Moving average with mask in Fortran

Tags: fortran, moving-average

I have to calculate the moving average of a masked dataset with dimensions (7320,8520) in Fortran. I wrote a subroutine that receives the data (TS) and outputs the averaged data (TS_NEW). The problem is that the code is taking too long to run (it actually never finishes, despite not running into memory issues). I wonder if there's a way to make the code more efficient. Below is the code I wrote:

```
SUBROUTINE avgwin(ts,winsize,size1,size2,sizelat,sizelon,ts_new)
implicit none
double precision, dimension(size1,size2),INTENT(IN) :: ts
double precision, dimension(winsize,winsize) :: store
double precision, dimension(sizelon,sizelat),INTENT(OUT) :: ts_new
integer :: j,k
integer :: A, B
integer,INTENT(IN) :: winsize,size1,size2,sizelat,sizelon
logical, dimension(size1,size2) :: mask,mask2
double precision :: SUMVAR, COUNTVAR
A=1
B=1

mask = ts > 0 !Mask to highlight all the OK values
mask2 = ts < 0 !Mask to highlight all the values to be discarded
do j=1,sizelat !Looping through latitude
    do k=1,sizelon !Looping through longitude
        if (ALL(mask2(k:k+winsize-1,j:j+winsize-1)) .eqv. .true.) then
            ts_new(B,A) = -100 !Adds a fill value if all the elements are to be discarded
            B=B+1
        else
            SUMVAR = sum(ts(k:k+winsize-1,j:j+winsize-1),     MASK=mask(k:k+winsize-1,j:j+winsize-1))
            COUNTVAR = count(mask(k:k+winsize-1,j:j+winsize-1))
            ts_new(B,A) = SUMVAR/COUNTVAR
            B=B+1
        end if
    end do
    B=1
    A=A+1
end do
END SUBROUTINE

program test
implicit none
double precision, dimension(7320,8520) :: DATA
double precision, dimension(:,:),allocatable :: DATA_NEW
integer :: sizelat, sizelon, i, j, len1, len2, winsize
integer, dimension(3) :: sizes

len1 = 7320
len2 = 8520
do i=1,8520
    do j=1,7320
        DATA(j,i)= i !Just for testing purposes
    end do
end do

sizes(1:3) = (/300,301,302/)
    do w=1,3
       winsize = sizes(w)
       sizelon = len1-winsize+1
       sizelat = len2-winsize+1
       allocate(DATA_NEW(sizelon,sizelat))
       CALL avgwin(DATA,winsize,len1,len2,sizelat,sizelon,DATANEW)
    end do

end program test
```

Comment: Please show the complete subroutine, see [mcve]. Better even more code. Especially with performance questions, usually one must do tests. So the code you show should be enough to be able to perform such tests. It is extremely hard to say anything definitive about performance without testing.

Comment: How large is the window? Did you try smaller problems? Did it finish? I would really ask for the complete code.

Comment: I included the entire code. I believe part of the problem is the input data that is in double precision format. But I'm just starting with Fortran, so I don't know a lot about it

Comment: It took over 8 hours to run for only one window size, and a pretty big one (300). I added a few other ones (301, 302, etc) and a day later it hadn't finished, and the job got shut down in the cluster. The intention was to run it for a range of window sizes, starting at small ones such as 2 and 3.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the help! If you don't mind, let me just ask two more questions. How can I keep track of the time for each iteration (or each part of the program)? Also, I was wondering if there was a way to do a "semi-moving window". That is, instead of advancing one row/column, the program would advance 1/2 or 1/4 of the window size. My problem has been predicting the size of the new dataset, to allocate. Any thoughts on how could I do that? Thanks!!

Comment: Do you need to do the all in ALL(mask2(k:k+winsize-1,j:j+winsize-1)) .eqv. .true.) ? Once a False value drops into this range you know you won't need a fill value for at least the next  winsize values, correct? If I am right (and it is very early in the morning here) this could save a fair few operations, though the code will need a bit of restructuring.

Comment: *How can I keep track of the time for each iteration (or each part of the program)?* You can use `system_clock()` just search for in on this site and you will find a few examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not sure if this meets the OP's purpose, how about first collecting data along one dimension and then collecting the processed data again along another dimension (i.e., partial summation)? For example, if we consider a simpler problem of summing `data( 1:L, 1:L )` over moving window of size `w`, there may be three different ways to achieve this:

```
program main
    implicit none
    real, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: data, direct, part1, part2
    integer :: i1, i2, L, S, w
    real :: t1, t2

    L = 2000
    w = 50
    S = L - w + 1

    allocate( data( L, L ), direct( S, S ), &
              part1( L, S ), part2( S, S ) )

!> test data

    do i2 = 1, L
    do i1 = 1, L
        data( i1, i2 ) = mod( i1 + i2, 2 )
    enddo
    enddo

!> method 1: direct sum (cost = O( S^2 * w^2 ))

    call cpu_time( t1 )
    do i2 = 1, S
    do i1 = 1, S
        direct( i1, i2 ) = sum( data( i1:(i1 + w - 1), i2:(i2 + w - 1) ) )
    enddo
    enddo
    call cpu_time( t2 )
    print *, "time (s) = ", t2 - t1

!> method 2: partial sum (cost = O( S^2 * w * 2 ))

    call cpu_time( t1 )
    do i2 = 1, S
    do i1 = 1, L
        part1( i1, i2 ) = sum( data( i1, i2:(i2 + w - 1) ) )
    enddo
    enddo

    do i2 = 1, S
    do i1 = 1, S
        part2( i1, i2 ) = sum( part1( i1:(i1 + w - 1), i2 ) )
    enddo
    enddo
    call cpu_time( t2 )
    print *, "time (s) = ", t2 - t1

    print *, "error = ", maxval( abs( part2 - direct ) )

!> method 3: an improved version of method 2 (cost = O( S^2 ))

    call cpu_time( t1 )
    do i1 = 1, L
        part1( i1, 1 ) = sum( data( i1, 1:w ) )
        do i2 = 2, S
            part1( i1, i2 ) = part1( i1, i2-1 ) &
                    - data( i1, i2-1 ) + data( i1, i2+w-1 )
        enddo
    enddo

    do i2 = 1, S
        part2( 1, i2 ) = sum( part1( 1:w, i2 ) )
        do i1 = 2, S
            part2( i1, i2 ) = part2( i1-1, i2 ) &
                    - part1( i1-1, i2 ) + part1( i1+w-1, i2 )
        enddo
    enddo
    call cpu_time( t2 )
    print *, "time (s) = ", t2 - t1

    print *, "error = ", maxval( abs( part2 - direct ) )

end program
```

Then, `gfortran-7.2 -O3 test.f90` seems to give some nice speedup:

```
 time (s) =    9.64789867
 time (s) =   0.345023155
 error =    0.00000000
 time (s) =    8.60958099E-02
 error =    0.00000000
```

To calculate moving average with mask, a similar approach may work somehow. If we search the net, there may be other (better) approaches/libraries for such moving average, because it is very common calculation...